# JavaScript's map() method is failing with the error "map is not a function"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dictionary

I am trying to get out a list of items from the array from an API but when I use the map function on items it says the map is not a function.

```
import React from 'react'
import { useState } from 'react';
const axios = require('axios');

const Api = () => {

const [items, setItems] = useState([]);

   const getUser = async () => {
        try {
          const response = await axios.get('http://localhost:5000/api/products');
          console.log(response);
          setItems (JSON.stringify(response));
        } catch (error) {
          console.error(error);
        }
      
}

return (
    <div>
        <button onClick={getUser}> Fetch Data</button>
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        {items}
    </div>
)
```

}

```
export default Api
```

Comment: what is `setItems`?  why  use `JSON.stringfy()` instead of `JSON.parse()`?

Comment: Axios usually returns the data (and parses it) in the form `response.data`. So try adding that to your state. And don't stringify the data. Why are you doing that?

Comment: You have `JSON.stringify()` your data, which makes it a string and `array#map` is not defined on string. You need to access `response.data` and check if it is array and then iterate over it using array function.

Comment: I tried setItems(response.data); but it says × Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {_id, name, price, imageUrl, __v}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't use `JSON.stringify`. since it's already object

Just change it to below code

```js
  const response = await axios.get('http://localhost:5000/api/products');
  setItems(response.data);
```

Comment: I tried  console.log(typeof response.data); and it says its an object. So, what do i do?

Comment: Console.log the output and update your answer which data youd like to render from response.data

Answer (score 0):

`axios.get()` method returns the `object` and you can't use the `map()` method on an object as it's been defined on the `prototype` of an array. You can find more details of `Array.prototype.map()` [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

First of all, let's understand what `axios.get()` method returns.

```
{
  // `data` is the response that was provided by the server
  data: {},

  // `status` is the HTTP status code from the server response
  status: 200,

  // `statusText` is the HTTP status message from the server response
  statusText: 'OK',

  // `headers` the HTTP headers that the server responded with
  // All header names are lower cased and can be accessed using the bracket notation.
  // Example: `response.headers['content-type']`
  headers: {},

  // `config` is the config that was provided to `axios` for the request
  config: {},

  // `request` is the request that generated this response
  // It is the last ClientRequest instance in node.js (in redirects)
  // and an XMLHttpRequest instance in the browser
  request: {}
}
```

You can find more details [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios#example). That means the actual data you are looking for resides in `response.data`. You need to extract it.

```
const { data } = response;
```

Now you need to analyze and process the `data` into the `React` renderable format.

Answer (score 0):

It worked by setItems(response.data)

```
import React from 'react'
import { useState } from 'react';
const axios = require('axios');

const Api = () => {

const [items, setItems] = useState([]);

   const getItems = async () => {
        try {
          const response = await axios.get('http://localhost:5000/api/products');
          console.log(response.data);
          
          setItems (response.data);
         
          console.log(response.data)
        } catch (error) {
          console.error(error);
        }
        
}

return (
    <div>
        <button onClick={getItems}> Fetch Data</button>
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
       
        {items.map((item)=>(
            <div >
                <h1>{item.name}</h1>
                <h2>{item.price}</h2>
            </div>
        ))}


    </div>
)
```

}

```
export default Api
```